# Transition on bootstrap modal height doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, bootstrap-modal

I'm using a Bootstrap (v3) modal as login screen. The login screen contains a "password forgotten" button which hides the main login form and shows the forgotten password form using simple jQuery.

The forgotten password form is 75px less tall than the login form, so the modal resizes. It does so rather bluntly, however, so I wanted to apply a CSS transition on the modal height to make the resizing more smooth.

Sadly, none of the things I tried, worked. I tried setting the transition property on the .modal class and on .modal-dialog; I tried setting the transition to !important. I even tried doing the transitions using jQuery animate, but when I did that the modal first resizes, then shrinks/grows even further using the jQuery animation, and then jumps back to the "good" height, so that didn't work as well.

Any options?

(EDIT)

HTML:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Login</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="default">
                        <h2>Welcome back!</h2>

                        <div class="form">
                            <form id="loginform" method="post" action="php/login-processor.php">
                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="button button-red" />
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <p class="link" id="topass">I forgot my password</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="forgotpass hidden">
                        <h2>Request a new password</h2>

                        <div class="form">
                            <form id="passforgottenform" method="post" action="php/password-forgotten-processor.php">
                                <input type="email" name="email-forgot-password" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Request" class="button button-red" />
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <p class="link" id="back">&lt; Back to the login screen</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#topass").click(function(){
    $(".default").addClass("hidden");
    $(".forgotpass").removeClass("hidden");
});

$("#back").click(function(){
    $(".default").removeClass("hidden");
    $(".forgotpass").addClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far .

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code and share with us.

Comment: Don't know if the code helps, but here you are

Comment: CSS transitions need start and final value otherwise doesn't works (if modal have height auto).

Comment: @GermanoPlebani thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm, figured it out.

jQuery:

```
$(".forgotpass").hide();

$("#topass").click(function(){
    $(".default").hide();
    $(".forgotpass").fadeIn();
    $(".modal-content").addClass("short");
});

$("#back").click(function(){
    $(".forgotpass").hide();
    $(".default").fadeIn();
    $(".modal-content").removeClass("short");
});
```

SCSS:

```
.modal-content {
    height: 415px;
    transition: height 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);

    &.short {
        height: 340px;
    }
}
```